# Loop over java Map with scalate's mustache implementation

Tags: java, scala, mustache, scalate

Can mustache loop over a java Map? My object:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapTest
```

Tried this in my mustache template:

```
{{#mapTest}}
  {{.}}
{{/mapTest}}
```

That spits out a string representation (`mapTest.toString()`) of the entire object but doesn't loop at all.

---

Update: In hunting through the source I'm getting closer but still not sure how to do it. https://github.com/scalate/scalate/blob/ec981338c067fcf37106fb5f3bdf2fa8c4e458ca/scalate-core/src/main/scala/org/fusesource/scalate/mustache/Scope.scala#L124-125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer on the mailing list...

http://groups.google.com/group/scalate/msg/100df004001d84f0

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Didn't expect a link-only answer from such known expert 

Answer (score 1):

You could [convert the Java Map to a Scala Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918956/convert-java-map-to-scala-map).

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val myScalaMap = myJavaMap.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala.toSet)
```

I wouldn't hack the template to accommodate a Java object.