# Convert Java Map to Scala Map

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have a java map: `java.util.Map<SomeObject, java.util.Collection<OtherObject>>`
and I would like to convert it to the scala map: `Map[SomeObject, Set[OtherObject]]`

I have used **mapAsScalaMap** but the result is not quite what I want, the result is: `Map[SomeObject, java.util.Collection[OtherObject]]`. How can I fix it to also convert the collection to a set?

NOTE: actually my original problem was to convert google's `ArrayListMultimap<SomeObject, OtherObject>` to a `MultiMap[SomeObject, OtherObject]` but since this was not possible I've split the problem. If you have a solution for the original problem, I'll also accept it as the answer.

Comment: look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127238/convert-java-util-mapstring-object-to-scala-collection-immutable-mapstring

Comment: and this page: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_46.html

Comment: @LutherBlisset: It has the same result as mapAsScalaMap: Map[SomeObject, java.util.Collection[OtherObject]]

Comment: @LutherBlisset: Also, the docu page does not say anything about the conversion of nested types. I've tried to convert it to Map[SomeObject, Iterable[OtherObject]], since Collection is automatically converted to Iterable, but I get the same result as before.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Edit**: the recommended way is now to use `JavaConverters` and the `.asScala` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val myScalaMap = myJavaMap.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala.toSet)
```

This has the advantage of not using magical implicit conversions but explicit calls to `.asScala`, while staying clean and consise.

---

*The original answer with `JavaConversions`*:

You can use `scala.collection.JavaConversions` to implicitly convert between Java and Scala:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val myScalaMap = myJavaMap.mapValues(_.toSet)
```

Calling `mapValues` will trigger an implicit conversion from the java `Map` to a scala `Map`, and then calling `toSet` on the java collection with implicitly convert it to a scala collection and then to a `Set`.

By default, it returns a mutable `Map`, you can get an immutable one with an additional `.toMap`.

Short-ish example:

```
scala> val a: java.util.Map[String, java.util.Collection[String]] = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.Collection[String]]
a: java.util.Map[String,java.util.Collection[String]] = {}

scala> val b = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
b: java.util.ArrayList[String] = []

scala> b.add("hi")
res5: Boolean = true

scala> a.put("a", b)
res6: java.util.Collection[String] = []

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val c = a.mapValues(_.toSet)
c: scala.collection.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = Map(a -> Set(hi))

scala> c.toMap
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = Map(a -> Set(hi))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the "mapValues(_.toSet)" part

Comment: @Ha11owed People recommend converters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala and comments to http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html

Comment: Nowadays JavaConversions are deprecated:

`@deprecated("use JavaConverters", since = "2.12.0")`

The transparent conversions provided here are considered fragile because they can result in unexpected behavior and performance.
Therefore, this API has been deprecated and JavaConverters should be used instead. JavaConverters provides the same conversions, but through extension methods.

Answer (score 5):

Immutable Map
`myJavaMap.asScala.toMap`

Mutable Map
`myJavaMap.asScala`

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do this from java:

```
List<Tuple2<A, B>> tuples = javaMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> Tuple2.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

scala.collection.Map scalaMap = scala.collection.Map$.MODULE$.apply(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(tuples).toSeq());
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373345/5209935

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Java Map into Scala Map using the below function:

```
val scalaMap = javaMap.asScala;
```

For using this you need to import the import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ library.

Hope this helps.