# How to Write Spark Stream ( Dstream / JavaDStream ) into Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have tried this Java code with following latest maven artifact.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.benfradet/spark-kafka-writer_2.10/0.4.0
As well as previous one - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.benfradet/spark-kafka-writer_2.10/0.1.0
But following code doesn't allow me to compile with Java 1.8 and Eclipse Oxygen latest IDE.

### ---IMPORT SECTION--

```
import com.github.benfradet.spark.kafka.writer.DStreamKafkaWriter;

import com.github.benfradet.spark.kafka.writer.KafkaWriter;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import scala.Function1;

import scala.Option;

import scala.Serializable;
```

---

```
Map<String, Object> producerConfig = new HashMap<String, Object>();
producerConfig.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
producerConfig.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class);
producerConfig.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class);

        KafkaWriter<String> kafkaWriter = new DStreamKafkaWriter<>(lines.dstream(), scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class));

        Function1<String, ProducerRecord<String, String>> f = new MyFunc<String, ProducerRecord<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public ProducerRecord<String, String> apply(final String s) {
                return new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", s);
            }
        };

        kafkaWriter.writeToKafka(producerConfig, f,Option.empty());
```

KafkaWriter.writerToKafka(producerConfig,f,Option.empty) --- Line gives me a following Error on Eclipse IDE

[image: spark-kafka-writer-error]

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The kafka writer's [`writeToKafka` method](https://github.com/BenFradet/spark-kafka-writer/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/benfradet/spark/kafka/writer/KafkaWriter.scala#L98) takes a `scala.collection.Map` while in this attempt, we're using a `java.util.Map`

The [official Java example](https://github.com/BenFradet/spark-kafka-writer#java-usage) uses an `asScala` transformation, but I don't know where that comes from. ( It doesn't seem legit as it looks like it's using Scala implicit conversions from `scala.collection.JavaConverters`, but that won't work in Java)

The simplest solution would be to instantiate a `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`  although I would recommend migrating the job to use Scala instead.

---

If you are using Spark >= v2.2, the easiest way to write to kafka is to transform your data into a `Dataset` or `DataFrame` and use the `DataFrameWriter` like this:

```
data.write.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","...") 
  .option("topic", "abcTopic" )
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/loc")
  .save()
```

(AFAIK, this is not documented anywhere I could find.)

Comment: Yep for the "producerConfig" they have used such as "asScala" transformation. looks further this comment - https://github.com/benfradet/spark-kafka-writer/issues/59#issuecomment-308849837

And I have put message for this original ( Spark-Kafka-Writer ) creators as following
https://github.com/benfradet/spark-kafka-writer/issues/59#issuecomment-333434591

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918956/convert-java-map-to-scala-map for converting a java map to a scala map. `JavaConverters` does not rely on implicits unlike `JavaConversions`.

Comment: @BenFradet I'm afraid it does rely on implicits and only works in Scala. It adds an explicit `asJava`/`asScala` methods using the 'pimp my library' pattern. See: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/DecorateAsJava.scala#L100

Comment: @BenFradet this can probably be used in the place: `JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMap(javaMap)` : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html#mapAsScalaMap[A,B](m:java.util.Map[A,B]):scala.collection.mutable.Map[A,B]